# Make WordPress site secure through HTTPS and SSL

Tags: https

I want to make my worpress site secure through HTTPS. In fact I did install the SSL certificate, but my site is still not secured (it doesn't show the green button, but a yellow one.  Problem at the moment seems to be 1 HTTP link in the header of the pages (besides the statcounter plugin, which I will deactivate once all the other problems are solved to make my site secure.

This problem is the second line in the source code in the header;

```
<html xmlns="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
```

Does anybody know how I can edit this line, and change the HTTP link into a HTTPS, or delete the line?

Comment: Do not place URLs in the Question Title, instead use the title to describe your question's "problem".

Answer (score 1):

If the meta tag is generated by your theme, you can rewrite the URL to `https://` if the whole site is forced to use SSL, or better yet, use `is_ssl()` to check if the page is using `https://` and write the URL on the fly.

You may have problems with plugins that don't take SSL into account and hard-code links like this one. If that's the case, ask the author to change it, or find/create a new one.